# how to configure bitnami on virtualbox windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, apache-http-server

I need to develop a website on my localhost

unfortunately, i had another project going, on the localhost

and now the new project needs imports to the database and other folders

i have tried importing it several times, each time resulting in complete erasure of whatever i had before, forcing me to restore everything from backup

so i decided i'd install virtualbox and windows 7 virtual machine, and try to run apache from there, but apache refuses to run inside the virtual box

the desired situation is to be : localhost on host machine and localhost on guest machine to be two different locations, so that anychange to host machine doesnt affect guest, and guest doesnt affect host.

how do i achieve that?

Comment: Could you past the error you get when running Apache in the VM?

Comment: the error message says that the port is being used, but i just installed everything 2 hours ago, didnt change any ports

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do it make the virtual machine (VM) use a `NAT` connection and not `Bridged`. If it's `Bridged` you will basically use the same `NIC (Network Interface Card)` as the host system. Meaning if you use port 80 on the host it's busy for the VM. `NAT` will set a new IP (Virtual NIC) on the VM and there will be no collision.

This might be a good read to understand the concept, and how to configure it. 
[VirtualBox networking](http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.se/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-two.html).